# asp.net mvc fix (correcting) data before each action. Perform in Model or Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm developing something like wizard with steps (controllers) and uses `DerivedModel1`, `DerivedModel2`,etc which is inherits from `BaseModel` and extends them with extra properties.
Models - only data, without business logic. All logic performed by services in controllers action for example _step1Service.GetRelated(model.id).

Now I want to not just validate Model (for this case there is `ValidationAttribute`) but fix invalid data in `BaseModel`:

```
 public class BaseModel
 {
     public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
 }
```

`StartDate` should be greater than today. User can select invalid date and instead of validation error application should fix this value (reset to default?).

In my first attempt I added service for validating/correcting `StartDate` and call in each Action:

```
public ActionResult Index(DerivedModel1 model)
{
_svc.fixModel(model);

if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
return View();
}

... do stuff with valid data
}
```

But don't like that, because have to add this line to each controller and action.
Then I add this correction to `StartDate` setter. It's looks better, but this breaks popular MVC paradigm that all logic should be in controller (or maybe i misunderstood something?)
I was thinking about possible solutions of this problem: ActionFilterAttribute, custom ModelBinder? But not sure is this right way and whether it work.
What you think about that?

Comment: If you are going to permit loose validation on data such as `StartDate`, why not, instead of defaulting arbitrary values, or making assumptions, just allow for nulls throughout your model (e.g. make StartDate a `Nullable<DateTime>` and adjust for this in your database. I would rather know that I have no data than have valid data which has no meaning / no trustworthiness?

Comment: there can be another validation rules that `fixModel` shouldn't fix (dependent on another inputs. it is important that the user himself corrected data). StartDate can't be null, it's main option in wizard. There is javascript validation for this field, so user can't choose invalid date, but I want also add validation at server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must implement IModelBinder to achieve this.

first define your custom model binder like this:

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
   public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            // Get the raw attempted value from the value provider
            DateTime incomingDate = (DateTime) bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("datefield").AttemptedValue;
            //validate and correct date here ...
            return new BaseModel{ DateMember =  incomingDate };
        }
}
```

then register your custom model binder such:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
       ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof (BaseModel), new MyCustomModelBinder());          
}
```

and your controller :

```
public ActionResult YourAction([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder )] BaseModel model)
{
      return Content("Ok");
}
```

Comment: So I have to add `ModelBinder`s for DerivedModel1 and DerivedModel2? Or create derived models based on rules in binder and then cast in action?

Comment: it is up to you.you can do either way.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between validation and business rules. Objects can (and often should) be responsible to make sure they are in a valid state themselves.

Comment: Yes, I can add validationattribute for model validation. but also want to resetting invalid values to valid - is this business rule?